# Rasa handling multiple time entity

Tags: python, rasa

I am developing a doctors appointment reminder bot using rasa where the user says
`i have appointment at 9am on april 10 and remind me at 7am on april 20`

how can i extract values for appointment time and reminder time slots

Answer (score 0):

Set date and times as entities in your `nlu_data.md` file as below:

```
## intent: reminder
- i have appointment at [9am](time) on [april 10](date) and remind me at [7am](time) on [april 20](date)
- remind me about my appointment on [1st April](date) at [7am](time) on [March 31](date) at [11 pm](time)
```

Add few more examples and variations of datetime to train better.

In `action.py` extract these values using `tracker.get_entities()`

Though you will have to write your own logic to differentiate reminder datetime and appointment datetime. Generally your appointment datetime will be greater than reminder

PS: Don't forget to add these entity names into your `domain` file

Comment: I agree with this but would add that it is better to extract date & time entities using [`DucklingHTTPExtractor`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/entity-extraction/#dates-amounts-of-money-durations-distances-ordinals) rather than using custom entities